# Do you need to add ...restProps for compound components in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a course and for the footer, they added ...restProps for every element. I don't understand why you need to do that if you're simply just creating a footer with no properties.

Here is the code

```
      export default function Footer({ children, ...restProps }) {
        return <Container {...restProps}>{children}</Container>;
      }

      Footer.Row = function FooterRow({ children, ...restProps }) {
        return <Row {...restProps}>{children}</Row>;
      };

      Footer.Column = function FooterColumn({ children, ...restProps }) {
        return <Column {...restProps}>{children}</Column>;
      };

      Footer.Link = function FooterLink({ children, ...restProps }) {
        return <Link {...restProps}>{children}</Link>;
      };

      Footer.Title = function FooterTitle({ children, ...restProps }) {
        return <Title {...restProps}>{children}</Title>;
      };
```

Here is where it is actually implemented

```
           <Footer>
            <Footer.Title>Questions? Contact us.</Footer.Title>
            <Footer.Break />
            <Footer.Row>
              <Footer.Column>
                <Footer.Link href="#">Home</Footer.Link>
                <Footer.Link href="#">About Us</Footer.Link>
                <Footer.Link href="#">Contact Us</Footer.Link>
                <Footer.Link href="#">Support</Footer.Link>
              </Footer.Column>
```

so far I understand why you add children because you need your footer menus text to show up, but I don't get why you need to add ...restProps to every footer element when only the links have something that you can customize.

Am I missing something, or is it not necessary to do this? Is this a proper way for creating a footer with compound components?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: You don't NEED to pass those props down, but you SHOULD.

Long answer:

You pass `restProps` to the returned component because that way you can define the props of the internal component from outside via the parent component. Let's say your `Container` component has a `width` prop. Defining your `Footer` without passing `restProps` you won't be able to set the `width` prop (or default props like `style`). So this:

```
<Footer width={100} />
```

Works if you use `...restProps`, and sets the `width` of the `Container` to 100, but it doesn't do anything if you don't.

Comment: Also important for general HTML props like `id`. If I set `id` on my Header, I'd expect it to be passed down and not just swallowed by the implementation.

Comment: Sometimes though you don't want to blindly just pass *everything* down to the DOM, *some* react props don't make for valid html attributes. However, you can simply destructure these props and continue to pass the rest.